# Bi Monthly dates, how?

Tags: date, datetime

I have the vb net code for first and last day of the Quarter, but I am trying to do this for first and last day of Bi monthly period ( which end on these months Feb, Apr, Jun, Aug, Oct, Dec)

So the bimonthly start and end dates are
Jan 1 to Feb 28 (or 29)
Mar 1 to Apr 30, 
May 1 to Jun 30, 
etc

Any ideas how to do this? (in Vb thanks)

```
'To get the first day of the quarter
Public Shared Function xFirstDayOfQuarter(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim currQuarter As Integer = (Month(theDay) - 1) \ 3 + 1
    Dim FirstDayQuarter As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), 3 * currQuarter - 2, 1)
    Return FirstDayQuarter
End Function
'To get the last day of the quarter
Public Shared Function xLastDayOfQuarter(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim currQuarter As Integer = (Month(theDay) - 1) \ 3 + 1
    Dim LastDayQuarter As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), 3 * currQuarter + 1, 0)
    Return LastDayQuarter
End Function
```

This how far I got ..

```
    Private Function DayOfBiMonth(ByVal theDay As DateTime, ByVal FirstOrLast As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim res As DateTime = Util.gBASEDATE
    Dim Mth As Integer = Month(theDay)
    Dim Yr As Integer = Year(theDay)
    Dim BiMonth As Integer = -1

    Select Case Mth
        Case Is = 1, 2
            If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
                BiMonth = 1
            ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
                BiMonth = 2
            End If
        Case Is = 3, 4
            If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
                BiMonth = 3
            ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
                BiMonth = 4
            End If
        Case Is = 5, 6
            If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
                BiMonth = 5
            ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
                BiMonth = 6
            End If
        Case Is = 7, 8
            If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
                BiMonth = 7
            ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
                BiMonth = 8
            End If
        Case Is = 9, 10
            If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
                BiMonth = 9
            ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
                BiMonth = 10
            End If
        Case Is = 11, 12
            If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
                BiMonth = 11
            ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
                BiMonth = 12
            End If
    End Select

    If FirstOrLast = 1 Then
        res = DateSerial(Yr, BiMonth, 1)
    ElseIf FirstOrLast = 2 Then
        res = DateSerial(Yr, BiMonth, 20)
        res = Util.LastDayOfMonth(res)
    End If

    Return res
End Function
Private Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim FirstDayMonth As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), Month(theDay), 1)
    Dim LastDayMonth As DateTime = FirstDayMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
    Return LastDayMonth
End Function
```

Comment: So what have you tried?  Your code should work just by changing from 3-month groupings to 2-month groupings.

Comment: Changing 3 to 2, just gives the month before, and the month after and not the  Bi-Monthly Jan to Feb, Mar to Apr, May to Jun, Jul-Aug, etc only pattern.

Comment: *************************

Comment: What's the point of that `20` in the DateSerial call?  (Not that it matters, your `LastDayOfMonth` throws it away anyway)

Comment: The point of the 20, is just a fill, lastdayofmonth secures issues with leap year

Comment: So what problems are you still seeing?

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag your question accordingly to attract those who know about it to your question,

Answer (score 0):

This works best

```
      'To get last day of BIMonth 2,4,6,8,12
    Public Shared Function LastDayOfBiMonth(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
        Dim FirstDayBiMonth As DateTime = FirstDayOfBiMonth(theDay)
        Dim LastDayBiMonth As DateTime = FirstDayBiMonth.AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)
        Return LastDayBiMonth
    End Function
    'To get first day of BIMonth 1,3,5,7,9,11
    Public Shared Function FirstDayOfBiMonth(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
        Dim Mnth As Integer = Month(theDay)
        If Mnth Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Mnth = Mnth - 1
        End If
        Dim FirstDayBiMonth As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), Mnth, 1)
        Return FirstDayBiMonth
    End Function
```